# Netty: Difference between using sync() and addListener()

Tags: java, asynchronous, netty

In a server handler, I have the following method:

```
private void writeResponse(HttpObject currentObj, ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    Promise<String> promise = client.run(); // client.run() will return a promise
    // the promise contains the result string I need for http response.
    promise.sync();
    // this method sends http response back, promise.getNow() is the content for the response.
    writeResponse(currentObj, ctx, promise.getNow()); 

}
```

This method is to send a response after getting some data from a client (`client` in the code). And when I test this using browser, I did get the response content.

However, when I change it to become:

```
private boolean writeResponse(HttpObject currentObj, ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    Promise<String> promise = client.run();
    promise.addListener(new FutureListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void operationComplete(Future<String> future) throws Exception {
            if (future.isSuccess()) {
                writeResponse(currentObj, ctx, future.getNow()); // (1)
            } else {
                writeResponse(currentObj, ctx, "FAILED");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

it didn't work anymore. From my understanding, it think the second one should also work because I've confirmed that the code did enter (1) block (the `if (future.isSuccess())` block). But I didn't get any response in the browser. Can anyone explain it a little bit or point me to some references? I've found the comparison between `await()` and `addListener` in the document but it gives me the feeling that the two are similar to each other in function.

Thanks!

[update] I found this is because of this overload method:

```
private void writeResponse(HttpObject currentObj, ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String content) {
    FullHttpResponse response = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(
            HTTP_1_1, currentObj.decoderResult().isSuccess()? OK : BAD_REQUEST,
            Unpooled.copiedBuffer(content, CharsetUtil.UTF_8));

    response.headers().set(HttpHeaderNames.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");

    if (HttpUtil.isKeepAlive(request)) {
        // Add 'Content-Length' header only for a keep-alive connection.
        response.headers().setInt(HttpHeaderNames.CONTENT_LENGTH, response.content().readableBytes());
        response.headers().set(HttpHeaderNames.CONNECTION, HttpHeaderValues.KEEP_ALIVE);
    }
    ctx.write(response);
}
```

I shouldn't use ctx.write(response), but use ctx.writeAndFlush(response).

At first I use ctx.write(response) because I have the `readComplete` method to do flush for me.

```
public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    ctx.flush();
}
```

But it seems that when using `addListener` instead of `sync`, the `channelReadComplete` cannot do the flush. Any idea why?

Comment: Don't you need to add the FutureListener *before* you run the operation?

Comment: @JamesKPolk sorry for not expressing my code clearly. The `client.run()` will return a promise which contains the result string I need. So I think I first get the promise, and then after it completes, execute the callback function. Or the callback of `addListener` will not be executed in this case?

Comment: Your code is clear, I was just confused. Sorry for the bad info.

Comment: What is writeResponse doing ?

Comment: @Norman Maurer this writeResponse(HttpObject, ChannelHandlerContext, String ) is supposed to write HTTP response back to client.

Comment: sure but what code is in there ?

Comment: @Norman Maurer Sorry for replying late. I've updated it in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you just call `write(...)` in your `ChannelFutureListener` and not `writeAndFlush(...)`. Because of this your written data will never be flushed to the socket.

The `channelReadComplete(...)` may be triggered before the `ChannelFutureListener` is executed and so you end up in this situation.

So to make it short use `writeAndFlush(...)` in the listener.